# How do I remove (release the memory) object from an array of objects (dynamique memory allocation of objects)

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory, memory-management

I am working on a clone of the space invaders game in C++ using classes. I want that when the laser comes in contact with an alien (which is stored in an array of objects) that the memory containing this alien be released and that all the memories to the right of this alien be shifted by 1 spot, afterwhich I want to create a smaller temporary array that will store the remain objects, so that can I delete the original memory and then point back to the temporary memory.
(this may seem like a long process but it prevent me from having to check a isAlive bool throughout the game and makes the search function more efficient).

this is what I have so far:

```
Ennemi::Ennemi() :ExtraTerrestre(0, 0) {

    maxElements = 1; // int maxElements
    nbElements = 0; // int nbElements
    ptr = new Ennemi*[maxElements]; // (Ennemi **ptr)
}

int Ennemi::chercherElement(Ennemi element[]){

    int indice = 0;
    while (indice < nbElements && ptr[indice] != element)
        indice++;

    // opérateur ternaire, retourne l'indice si vrai, sinon retourne -1
    return indice < nbElements ? indice : -1;
}

void Ennemi::retirerEnnemi(Ennemi element[]) {
    int indice = chercherElement(element);

    // si un element est trouver active la condition
    if (indice != -1) {
        // preserver l'ordre du tableau
        for (int i = indice; i < (nbElements - 1); i++) {
            ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
        }
        nbElements--;
        maxElements = nbElements;

        // allocation d'une zone memoire
        double *ptrTemporaire = new double[maxElements];

        // copie des elements dans la nouvelle zone
        for (int i = 0; i < nbElements; i++) {
            ptrTemporaire[i] = ptr[i];
        }
        // on libere l'ancienne zone memoire
        delete[] ptr;

        // fait pointer le pointeur sur la nouvelle zone
        ptr = ptrTemporaire;
    }
}
```

P.S. Please don't suggest using vectors, I am trying to improve my understanding not do it the easy way.

Comment: That is not the only error, your code is not compilable and pretty much a big mess. If you want to work with raw array you need to understand that topic better.

Comment: Is the buffer a `Ennemi **ptr` or `Ennemi element[]`? It's unclear from your code.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to create a Linked list structure so that you will be able to easily  free the memory and shift the members .

Answer (score 0):

First of all this function may work correctly, but it is poorly designed:

```
int Ennemi::chercherElement(Ennemi element[]);
```

this function suppose to find index of element by a pointer, but your function name is `findElement` (pardon my French) and you pass array of elements. Though syntactically it is the same it would confuse reader including yourself, so it should be:

```
int Ennemi::findElementIndex( Ennemi *element );
```

(or translated back to French) now to make it completely proper we should notice that this method not suppose to change `element` nor internal data, so

```
int Ennemi::findElementIndex( const Ennemi *element ) const;
```

now your erasing data from array, your code is almost correct but you are missing code to delete object itself:

```
    if (indice != -1) {
       delete ptr[i]; // this missing
       // preserver l'ordre du tableau
       for (int i = indice; i < (nbElements - 1); i++) {
           ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
       }
       nbElements--;
   }
```

after that you are trying to shrink dynamically allocated data, do not do that. Allocating/deallocating memory is a pretty expensive operation so usually you expand when there is not enough room (and you should not expand by one but some delta) and you do not shrink back, because there is a big chance you will have to grow back again. Or you may at least shrink by some delta. For example when amount of elements == maxElemens / 2.

Also this line:

```
 double *ptrTemporaire = new double[maxElements];
```

you try to create array of doubles and assign it to array of pointers to `Ennemi`, this is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I forget to delete the object in question before moving the values. And yeah your right I don't need to progressively shrink the memory 1 by one, it is much more efficient to just keep track of the number of aliens (and reduce the search limit) and then shrink the memory later by some delta, And I did think of using *element (the value at the pointed region) but for some reason it didn't connect in my head :(. Still new to these concepts but thank a lot anyways.